# Debounce function running multiple time after timeout complete

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a debounce function that take the input of "SaveValue" which would take the value of the input and save that some where. Problem is it runs the "SaveValue" function multiple time one the debounce timeout in complete. I have many of these input and don't really want to be putting a bunch of onEventListeners through out the code. What is the best way to make this work.

```
<input id="testInput" onkeyup="debounce(() => { SaveValue(value, 'savehere', 'onhere') } , 300)();" type="text" />
```

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

```
function SaveValue(value1, value2, value3){
    console.log(`Save value of ${value1} here -> ${value2} on field -> ${value3}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a little testing on your code, and it seems the way the `debounce` function is being called in the `onkeyup` handler, is creating a new instance of the function call (and subsequently a new timer) for every event. This would result in the multiple calls.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
const dSaveValue = debounce(() => { SaveValue("value", 'savehere', 'onhere')}, 1000, false)

<input id="testInput" onkeyup="dSaveValue()" type="text" />
```

Lloyd

Comment: In the event that I had 30 or more of these inputs, all using SaveValue but with different arguments, would I have to create 30 version of the const. EG

const dSaveValue = debounce(() => { SaveValue("value", 'savehere1', 'onhere1')}, 1000, false)

const dSaveValue2 = debounce(() => { SaveValue("value", 'savehere2', 'onhere2')}, 1000, false)

etc

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this I have figured a way to make this re-useable. Thankyou Lloyd for clearing this up for me. Works great.

```
<input onkeyup="dSaveValue(value, 'DatabaseTable', 'DatabaseRow')" type="text" />
<input onkeyup="dSaveValue(value, 'DatabaseTable', 'DifferentDatabaseRow')" type="text" />
```

```
const dSaveValue = debounce((value1, value2, value3) => { SaveValue(value1, value2, value3)}, 1000, false)
```